# A better TypeScript definition for Error on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript

If you have typescript installed as a dependency in your NodeJS project then you'll find the definition for Error in the `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts` file:

```
interface Error {
    name: string;
    message: string;
    stack?: string;
}
```

The `stack` prop is optional because it's a non-standard Ecmascript prop.

NodeJS is based on V8 so from my understanding it's up to the V8 team to decide if stack is included in a `new Error()` object or not. And taking a leap of faith I'm going to say that this is so embedded now that a lot of code would break if this were to be removed so we can rely on this for a long time to come.

To simplify my NodeJS code I can do this:

```
type NodeError = Required<Error>;
```

This means that I won't get TypeScript warnings that my usage of `stack` might be undefined if I cast my Error to this type.

I feel that there might be another place that Error might be defined in the ecosystem that I haven't found yet that is based on V8 and might already have the `Error` type defined like this. For me the obvious place to look would be in `@types/node` as that is a representation of the Node API from TypeScript's perspective. From what I can see it builds on the ES5 types that have been previously mentioned and only adds Node specific APIs or differences.

Is there a "more standard" or "more robust" way to tell TypeScript that `stack` will be present that will safely persist into future versions of NodeJS and V8? i.e. I would rather have this type come from the publisher of the runtime that I'm targeting than me doing a cast.